# I need to click twice before data returns in console properly

Tags: reactjs

In this react component, I want to render the data into my console  when the 'TO FROM SELECTED UNITS' button is clicked by the user, but the button has to be pressed twice for the data to show in the console.

Please ignore:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Here is my code:

```
const unitTests = props => {
  const autoComplete = useContext(AutoCompleteContext)
  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)

  const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
  const targetObjectFromURL = query.get('object')

  const cookies = new Cookies()

  const [unitTestsData, setUnitTestsData] = useState(null)
  const [database, setDatabase] = useState('')
  const [targetObject, setTargetObject] = useState(null)
  const [unitTestsMode, setUnitTestsMode] = useState('Object')
  const [AddRemoveDatabaseChanges, setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges] = useState(null)
  const [AddRemoveDatabaseMode, setAddRemoveDatabaseMode] = useState('ADD')

  console.log(unitTestsData);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadUnitTests() {
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const [objectsAutoCompleteResults, databaseAutoCompleteResults] = await Promise.all([
        get('get_objects_autocomplete/all/all/b', user.user),
        get('get_databases_autocomplete/a', user.user)
      ])
      autoComplete.setObjectsAutoComplete(objectsAutoCompleteResults)
      autoComplete.setDatabasesAutoComplete(databaseAutoCompleteResults)
      if(targetObjectFromURL) setTargetObject(targetObjectFromURL)
      else if(cookies.get('table')) setTargetObject(cookies.get('table'))
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }

    onLoadUnitTests()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUnitTests() {
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const optionalParams = unitTestsMode === 'Object'
        ? `?type=object&target=${targetObject}`
        : `?type=database&target=${database}`
      const url = `get_unit_tests${optionalParams}`
      const results = await verifiedGet(url, user.user)
      if(results.status === 0) {
        setUnitTestsData(results.data)     
        } else if(results.status >= 20 && results.status <= 30) {
        snackbar.statusCheck(results)
        user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
      } else snackbar.statusCheck(results)
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }

    if(targetObject || database) getUnitTests()
  }, [targetObject,database])


  const onObjectSelect = (e, value) => {
    props.history.push(`/unittests?object=${value}`)
    setTargetObject(value)

    cookies.set('table', value, { path: '/'})
  }

  const onNewTestCaseClick = () => {
    props.history.push(`/createtest?object=${targetObject}`)
  }

  const onDatabaseSelect = (e, value) => setDatabase(value)

  const onChangeUnitTestsMode = (e) => setUnitTestsMode(e.target.getAttribute('value'))

  
  const onChangeAddRemoveMode = (e) => setAddRemoveDatabaseMode(e.target.getAttribute('value'))

  console.log(AddRemoveDatabaseMode);
  const addtoproduction = () => {

    let databaseChanges = unitTestsData.map(tests => { 
    return {
      "unit_test_id": tests.unit_test_template_id,
      "databases": tests.databases
    }
  })
     setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(databaseChanges)
  
  if(AddRemoveDatabaseChanges != null && AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'ADD'){
   
    console.log('added data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges);

  } else if (AddRemoveDatabaseChanges != null && AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'REMOVE') {
    
    console.log('removed data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges )

  }
  }

  return (
    <PageWrapper title='View Unit Tests'>
      <div className='Main UnitTestsAutoCompleteWrapper' style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <div style={{width: '30%', marginRight: '10px'}}>
          <DropdownSingle
            options={['Object', 'Database']}
            value='Object'
            name='Search unit tests'
            onChange={onChangeUnitTestsMode}
          />
        </div>

      {unitTestsMode === 'Object' ?
        <div>
          <AutoCompleteSingle
            name='Table'
            label='Table'
            options={autoComplete.objectsAutoComplete}
            onChange={autoComplete.onObjectAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
            onSelect={onObjectSelect}
            uniqueIdentifier={0}
            initialValue={targetObject}
          />
        </div> :
      
      
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <div style={{width: '100%'}}>
          <DropdownSingle
            options={['ADD', 'REMOVE']}
            value='ADD'
            name='Search unit tests'
            onChange={onChangeAddRemoveMode}
          />
        </div>
          <AutoCompleteSingle
            name='Database'
            label='Database'
            options={autoComplete.databasesAutoComplete}
            onChange={autoComplete.onDatabaseAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
            onSelect={onDatabaseSelect}
            uniqueIdentifier={1}
            style={{width: '1000%'}}
            />

          <div>
          <Button 
          text='TO/FROM SELECTED UNIT TESTS'
          onClick={addtoproduction}

           />
        </div>
        </div>

      }
      </div>
      
      {!unitTestsData ? null :
        !unitTestsData.length ?
        <div>
          This table has no associated unit tests
          <div style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
            <Button
              text='New Test Case'
              icon={<AddIcon className='ButtonIcon' />}
              onClick={onNewTestCaseClick}
              className='Button Dark Main'
              style={{width: '200px'}}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        :
        unitTestsMode === 'Object' ?
      <UnitTestsObjectView unitTestsData={unitTestsData}/>
      : <UnitTestsDatabaseView unitTestsData={unitTestsData} />
      }

      {!targetObject ? null :
        <div style={{position: 'fixed', bottom: '80px', right: '40px'}}>
          <Button
            text='New Test Case'
            icon={<AddIcon className='ButtonIcon' />}
            onClick={onNewTestCaseClick}
            className='Button Dark Main'
          />
        </div>
      }

    </PageWrapper>
  )
}

export default withRouter(unitTests)
```

Comment: just a note about "mostly code warning". usually, its a good idea to put this in a code sandbox, and link that codebox here, and post only the relevant snippets. you have so much code. also, a code box makes it easy for the community to run the project, look at errors and help you fix things faster.

Comment: Try not to just dump almost 200 lines of raw code for us to filter through. Try your best to narrow it down to responsible code and post that. Also, don't use the spam approach to get around that "mostly code" restriction. Adjust your question so that your detail is high enough and your code is minimal enough

Comment: To answer your question, the problem is that state changes are asynchronous. You can't call `setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(...)` then `console.log` it on the next line and see the change. Async stuff is deferred until all synchronous code has finished running.

Comment: also, its almost like you are punishing us for trying to help you. in the question, it says "TO FROM SELECTED UNITS" but the actual button says "TO/FROM SELECTED UNIT TESTS". and there is so much extra code, with data getting mapped from here to there to here and there. its like a true test of patience. we want to help you, but you should help us by posting slightly better questions.

Comment: ah thanks @Jayce444 what would bee the better solution for this?

Comment: @bloombloom well it depends what you want to do in response to that change, currently all you do is `console.log` the value. If you want to call some code in response to `AddRemoveDatabaseChanges` changing, then you can use `useEffect` with `AddRemoveDatabaseChanges` as a dependency, then in that effect check what the value is equal to and then run code accordingly. The effect will get the most recent value

Comment: Ah I see, so eventually this data will be sent as a POST request. I wanted to console log to make sure I had the right values.